# Best way to parse JSON with an unknown structure for comparison with a known structure?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a YAML file which I convert to JSON, and then to a Java object using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). This will be used as the standard definition which I will compare other YAML files against. The YAML files which I will be validating should contain fields with identical structures to my definition. However, it is very possible that it might contain fields with different structure, and fields that don't exist within my definition, as it is ultimately up to the user to create these fields before I receive the file. A field in the YAML to be validated can look like this, with the option of as many levels of nesting as the user wishes to define.

```
 LBU:
      type: nodes.Compute
      properties:
        name: LBU
        description: LBU
        configurable_properties: 
          test: {"additional_configurable_properties":{"aaa":"1"}}
        vdu_profile:
          min_number_of_instances: 1
          max_number_of_instances: 4
      capabilities:
        virtual_compute:
          properties:
            virtual_memory:
              virtual_mem_size: 8096 MB
            virtual_cpu:
              cpu_architecture: x86
              num_virtual_cpu: 2
              virtual_cpu_clock: 1800 MHz
      requirements:
      - virtual_storage:
          capability: capabilities.VirtualStorage
          node: LBU_Storage
```

Currently, I receive this YAML file and convert it to a JsonObject with Gson. It is not possible to map this to a Java object because of any possible unknown fields. My goal is to run through this file and validate every single field against a matching one in my definition. If a field is present that does not exist in the definition, or does exist but has properties that differ, I need to inform the user with specific info about the field.

So far, I am going the route of getting fields like this.

```
 for (String field : obj.get("topology_template").getAsJsonObject().get("node_template").getAsJsonObject().get(key).getAsJsonObject().get(
              obj.get("topology_template").getAsJsonObject().get("node_templates").getAsJsonObject().get(key).getAsJsonObject().keySet().toArray()[i].toString()).getAsJsonObject().keySet()) {
```

However, it seems that this is rather excessive and is very hard to follow for some deeply nested fields.

What I want to know is if there is a simpler way to traverse every field of a JsonObject, without mapping it to a Java object, and without explicitly accessing each field by name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like a streaming Json Parser:

Here's an example

```
String json
  = "{\"name\":\"Tom\",\"age\":25,\"address\":[\"Poland\",\"5th avenue\"]}";
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createParser(json);

String parsedName = null;
Integer parsedAge = null;
List<String> addresses = new LinkedList<>();

while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
    if ("name".equals(fieldname)) {
        jParser.nextToken();
        parsedName = jParser.getText();
    }

    if ("age".equals(fieldname)) {
        jParser.nextToken();
        parsedAge = jParser.getIntValue();
    }

    if ("address".equals(fieldname)) {
        jParser.nextToken();
        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            addresses.add(jParser.getText());
        }
    }
}
jParser.close();
```

Please find the documentation here:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi